# Geläufige mehrwortige Begriffe mit Adjektiv aus dem Englischen (»Best Practices«, »Daily Soap«, »Open Source«)

Tags: compound, writing, anglicism

Im Deutschen sind einige Begriffe aus dem Englischen geläufig, die aus mehreren Wörtern bestehen, wovon das erste ein Adjektiv ist. Beispiele:

- > Best Practices
- > Daily Soap
- > Open Source

**Wie muss mit solchen Begriffen in deutschen Texten verfahren werden?**

- Müssen sie in Anführungszeichen (bzw. kursiv) gesetzt werden?

  > »Open Source« ist eine tolle Sache.
  >   Ich schaue mir gerne eine *Daily Soap* an.

  Meines Wissens nach ist das erforderlich, wenn die Begriffe nicht geläufig sind, wenn der Begriff also als Fremdwort verwendet wird (dann wird der Begriff allerdings auch kleingeschrieben).
- Müssen Bindestriche gesetzt werden?

  > Open-Source ist eine tolle Sache.
  >   Ich schaue mir gerne eine Daily-Soap an.

  Meines Wissens nach ist eine [Durchkopplung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung#Fremdsprachliche_Begriffe) erforderlich, wenn der Begriff mit einem weiteren Wort verbunden wird: »Open-Source-Enzyklopädie«, »Daily-Soap-Fan«, »Best-Practices-Sammlung«.
- Müssen sie zusammengeschrieben werden?

  > Opensource ist eine tolle Sache.
  >   Ich schaue mir gerne eine Dailysoap an.
- Oder dürfen sie einfach so verwendet werden?

  > Open Source ist eine tolle Sache.
  >   Ich schaue mir gerne eine Daily Soap an.

Comment: Warum stellst du diese Frage, wenn du doch ohnehin die Antwort kennst?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: 1. kannte ich die Antwort noch nicht, als ich die Frage gestellt habe, 2. muss meine Antwort (bzw. die Interpretation der Quelle / bzw. die Antwort in der FAQ) nicht zwangsläufig richtig sein, 3. spricht nichts dagegen ([ganz im Gegenteil](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer))

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Stackexchange-Seiten sind keine Foren, in denen es in erster Linie um die Beantwortung der Fragen für die fragenden User geht, sondern Wissenssammlungen, und es wird explizit dazu aufgerufen, Fragen zu stellen und sie selbst zu beantworten. https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/fragen-deren-antwort-man-selbst-kennt

Comment: Die Annahme *nicht geläufig*, also *Fremdwort* ist falsch. Die meisten Fremdwörter sind sehr geläufig, beispielsweise Intention, circa, chillen und relaxen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  Ich weiß, ich zähle Erbsen, aber die eine Erbse würde ich deiner im Grunde durchaus richtigen Bemerkung doch hinzufügen wollen: Ja, Fragen selbst zu beantworten, ist hier durchaus gute Übung (vulgo Best Practice), aber nicht in der Frage selbst, sondern in einer Antwort, die gesondert veröffentlicht wird. Aber... na... gut. Welche Muscheln... (What shells.)

Answer (score 3):

[FAQ des Rechtschreibrats](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/service/fragen-und-antworten/):

> ### Wie schreibt man englische Wörter, die nicht im Wörterbuch stehen?
>
> […]
>
> #### 2. Verbindungen aus Adjektiv + Substantiv
>
> Bei der Schreibung von Verbindungen dieser Art ist die Betonung ausschlaggebend: Liegt die Betonung wie in *Hotline* hauptsächlich auf dem ersten Bestandteil oder sind beide Bestandteile wie in *Daily Soap* in etwa gleich stark betont? Im ersten Fall greift das deutsche Betonungsmuster („Erstbetonung“), im zweiten das englische. Da die Betonung wesentlich für die Schreibung des Deutschen ist, folgt die Schreibung ihr auch hier. In den Fällen, in denen beide Betonungsmuster gebräuchlich sind, sind beide Schreibungen zugelassen wie z.B. in *Blind Date*/*Blinddate*, *Slow Food*/*Slowfood*.
>
> […]

Demnach kommen nur zwei Optionen in Frage, abhängig von der Betonung:

- Zusammenschreibung (*Blinddate*)
- Mit Leerzeichen (*Blind Date*)

Bei den drei Beispielen aus meiner Frage dürften die Wörter in etwa gleich stark betont werden, also wären diese Schreibweisen korrekt:

- > Wir diskutieren heute **Best Practices**.
- > **Open Source** ist eine tolle Sache.
- > Ich schaue mir gerne eine **Daily Soap** an.

Answer (score -1):

Ich stimme dir zu. Bindestriche sind erforderlich in solchen Sätzen, wenn ein englisches Wort verwendet wird. Es sieht wie English aus, wenn man einen Bindestrich auslässt.